# Assigning same value to multiple class variables with same type

Tags: c#, winforms, class

I have some variables from winforms

```
buttonLink.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
buttonLink.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent;
buttonLink.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

Every time writing whole sequence is a bit too long so I was wandering if there's possibility to shorten it somehow like this

```
buttonLink.(BackColor & FlatAppearance(MouseDownBackColor & MouseOverBackColor) = Color.Transparent
```

Since it'd really simplify the code and it's weight, especially in bigger projects

I tried writing in () and just using & but it has no effect
Does anyone have some ideas?

Comment: That's not how it works. You have to assign each property individually. Best solution would be writing a function. You could try writing it like this: buttonLink.BackColor = buttonLink.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = buttonLink.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Transparent; But it does not look any more simple than individual assigning.

Comment: extract a function and set the properties there?

Comment: You can always build an extension method, applied to `ButtonBase`, where you set all background colors you want, so then you can have something like `[someButton].BackColorAll(Color.Transparent)`

Comment: It's very interesting example
Thanks everyone willing to help and I'm sorry for not replying for a long time. Question was of a sheer newbie's curiosity and I was able to gain some insight thanks to you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a function like this:

```
public void SetColor(Button button, Color color)
{
    button.BackColor = color;
    button.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = color;
    button.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = color;
}
```

And then invoke it like this:

```
SetColor(buttonLink, Color.Transparent);
```

In C# `&` is an AND binary operator, so it won't work like that.

To fix your try to make it inline:

```
buttonLink.BackColor = buttonLink.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = buttonLink.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

But it's not very pretty.

The thing you tried to write is possible in some languages, at example in VB there is `With` statement that work similar to that, but I'm not aware of such construction in C#.